# How can I align a "right" footer with the second column in a twocolumn document?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to recreate the footer in the attached image. The left footer is not a problem, but the right footer is the one I haven't been able to figure out. [image]

I'm using the fancyhdr package, but the \fancyfootoffset[r]{length} will set the offset of the end of the footer, not the start; and even if I could figure out the offset of the start, I think I will have problems aligning the page number to the end of the column. The only way I can think of right now is to somehow create a block inside the right footer that is the same width as the column, and use a horizontal space filler to push the text and page number to be flush with the start and end of the second column---but unfortunately I've not been able to figure out how to actually code it. How would I go about doing this right footer?

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Left footer text}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Needs to be aligned as image. \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about providing the community with a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that we can use to start working on your solution? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and provide a solid foundation from where we can work. Can you do that and include it in your post?

Comment: Hi @Werner, just added it, but also I finally was able to figure out how to code the boxes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Got around to figure out how to actually code the text box. It would simply be:

```
\fancyfoot[R]{\makebox[\columnwidth]{Right footer text \hfill \thepage}}
```

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Left footer text}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\makebox[\columnwidth]{Right footer text \hfill \thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```